# Write to csv header row using angular 4/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following piece of code which gets the data and writes it to csv file. But it is writing the data in the column. But I need that data to be in Header row. I tried changing the 'showLabels' : true/false back and forth to see if that will do the trick. But it didn't do what I want. Can some help me out what I am missing in this?

```
var options = { 
  fieldSeparator: ',',
  quoteStrings: '"',
  decimalseparator: '.',
  showLabels: true, 
  showTitle: false
};

new Angular2Csv(this.data, 'test', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`new Angular2Csv(this.data, 'test', { headers: Object.keys(this.data[0]) });`

Found this [issue](https://github.com/javiertelioz/angular2-csv/issues/27) addressing this.

Created [stackblitz: https://angular-gv4ut6.stackblitz.io](https://angular-gv4ut6.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Still no luck. getting the same way

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: Please have a look at the above plunker and let me know where I have do make changes

Comment: Hi. Can someone help me out with this. I am still facing this issue.

Comment: You need to look into the data you receive from service. Please elaborate clearly what data you receive and how do you want to create your csv.

I have created this [stackblitz: https://angular-gv4ut6.stackblitz.io](https://angular-gv4ut6.stackblitz.io) from your code and it is downloading   with headers.